# Is SystemParametersInfo DPI aware?

Tags: windows, winapi, dpi

Specifically, does "result" change in the following code when the DPI is increased via the windows control panel display settings?

```
UINT result = 0;
if(SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFOCUSBORDERHEIGHT, 0, &result, 0) != FALSE)
{
    result = ?;
}
```

The reason I can't check this myself is that I can't change the DPI setting on the computer I'm working on because the admin has disabled the option.

Answer (score 0):

The documents are unclear but in general the 3rd param is only in/out because the Win32 API here is overloaded as both a getter and a setter.  I would not expect this to change on a SET 
call but on the GET call you have above, yes it will change to indicate the current value.  Did you intend to actually post a SET call?  The question text implies you are trying to set the value.

For the following code, the value ought not to change:

```
UINT result = REQUIRED_NEW_VALUE;
if(SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOCUSBORDERHEIGHT, 0, &result, 0) != FALSE)
{
    // result == the same as what was input
}
```

For the code you posted, `result` will change from 0 to the current configured value:

```
UINT result = 0;
if(SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFOCUSBORDERHEIGHT, 0, &result, 0) != FALSE)
{
    // result == the current configured value
}
```

Comment: Erm, that's not what I meant I'm afraid. The code that I posted "retrieves the height, in pixels, of the top and bottom edges of the focus rectangle drawn by DrawFocusRect". In XP, at the default 96 DPI, "result" will be set to "1" by SystemParametersInfo. My question was whether, after setting the DPI of the system to a higher value using "Control Panel -> Display -> Settings -> Advanced", SystemParametersInfo will put a different value into "result". Eg. at twice the DPI I would expect it to set "result" to "2".

Comment: @sally - I see, sorry for the confusion.  Are you in a position to try this on a home desktop using Visual C++ Express Edition, say?